# How to remove a window's onclick event (Pebble.js)

Tags: pebble-js

I am writing a Pebble app in Pebble.js which needs to run different functions when the same button is pressed at different times throughout the app.

I can easily associate a function with a button:

```
dispWindow.on('click', 'up', function(e) {
  doSomething();
});
```

After `doSomething` runs a few times, I need to change what happens when the user clicks the "up" button in the `dispWindow` Window.  I can add this code:

```
dispWindow.on('click', 'up', function(e) {
  doSomethingElse();
});
```

However, when the user clicks the "up" button, `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` both fire. How do I remove `doSomething` from the "up" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) event, like this:

```
dispWindow.off('click');
```

Then, call the `on` event again after that:

```
dispWindow.on('click', 'up', function(e) {
  doSomethingElse();
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. By taking out the 'up' section I got it to work though: `dispWindow.off('click');`

Comment: Whoops. I fixed my answer. Check the check-mark if this answer worked for you, btw.